# Are the libtensorflow_jni and libtensorflow_jni_gpu jar dependencies mutually exclusive?

Tags: java, tensorflow, native

If we add both the libtensorflow_jni and the libtensorflow_jni_gpu to the maven pom or perhaps something like this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
   <artifactId>tensorflow</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
   <artifactId>libtensorflow_jni_gpu</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Can we expect that the built application will be able to run on and leverage both CPU and GPU platforms? 
Or are those libraries mutually exclusive?

Documentation is not particularly clear on this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/maven/README.md#artifact-structure

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not mutually exclusive. `libtensorflow_jni_gpu` has a superset of the functionality in that it allows leveraging both CPU and GPU (if available on the system of course) for operations.

However, `libtensorflow_jni_gpu` currently requires that CUDA libraries be installed on the system running the program (whether or not a GPU is physically installed).

Hope that helps.

Comment: in other words if i have a linux system with CUDA installed then i would be able to use the libtensorflow_jni_gpu for GPU and for CPU (if my system doesn't have GPUs)?

Still the conclusions in my answer above hold. If  someone mistakenly put both the libtensorflow_jni and the libtensorflow_jni_gpu jars on the class path then NativeLibrary.java  will try to load the first one it find on the classpath. The order of those though is not deterministic. 

Also there isn't a graceful way to fall back from the GPU to CPU jar library?

Answer (score 0):

I believe i have an answer of my question.

Based on the `libtensorflow_jni` and `libtensorflow_jni_gpu` jars structure and the [NativeLibrary.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/NativeLibrary.java) implementation i can conclude that their classpath namespaces overlap and therefore those native jars are **mutually exclusive**!

At any given moment one can have either

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>libtensorflow_jni</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

or

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>libtensorflow_jni_gpu</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

on the classpath but never both!

One practical implication of this is that your application need to build two separate deployment jars (one for CPU and one GPU environment).